# Clicking on specific ion-item button triggers the other buttons in ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic3

Lets suppose there are n elements in the array of item. So, the below html will display n items with arrow-dropup click button attached to every item.

```
 <div *ngFor="let item of medicineName; let i = index">
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item >
      <ion-thumbnail item-start  >
        <img src="/assets/imgs/tablet.png" class="thumbnail">
      </ion-thumbnail>
      <h2 style="color: #070779;font-weight: bold;">{{item.medicine_name}}</h2>
      <div class = "done" *ngIf="showDiv">
        <ion-icon name="done-all"></ion-icon>
      </div>
      <p>{{item.instruction}} | {{item.days}}</p>
      <button  ion-button clear item-end (click)="toggle()">
       <ion-icon name="arrow-dropup" *ngIf="visible[index]"></ion-icon>
   <ion-icon name="arrow-dropdown" *ngIf="!visible[index]"></ion-icon>
     </button>
     <button ion-button icon-only *ngIf="showBtn" style="width: 30%">SKIP</button>
     <button ion-button icon-only *ngIf="showBtn" (click)="showIcon()" style="width: 30%">TAKE</button>
   </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</div>
```

.ts code

```
toggle(index){
  this.visible[index] = !this.visible[index];
if(this.showBtn == true){
  this.showBtn = false;
} else {
  this.showBtn = true ;
}
```

[image]

**Requirement** : I only want the particular button change with visible=true, and not all the buttons.

**Problem** : When clicking on arrow `Click` button of respective ion-item, the other ion-item does not get effected.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're only using one variable for your display i.e. `visible`, therefore once you click on one, it's toggled to `true` and all the items show expanded.

You need to have multiple variables to handle the different dropdowns, add an index to your `ngFor`, and then change click handler to `(click)="toggle(index)"`

```
visible: boolean[];    

toggle(index) {
  this.visible[index] = !this.visible[index];
}
```

Comment: Getting TypeError: "can't assign to property 0 on false: not an object"

Comment: At what line in the code are you getting that error?

Comment: <ion-icon name="arrow-dropup" *ngIf="visible"></ion-icon><ion-icon name="arrow-dropdown" *ngIf="!visible"></ion-icon> .these lines gives error because here variable visible is not array.

Comment: You need to change the ngIf as well...
```*ngIf="visible[index]"```

Comment: What are you passing to the index? I have used this code before, I'm a 100% sure it works

Comment: 0,1,2.... i have already console log the value in toggle function and i am getting 0,1  in the log.

Comment: Can you update the code on your question to reflect the newest changes, maybe that way is better to help you